# SQL query to select products by tag in WooCommerce?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce store with products which are either tagged as a smartphone or tablet. I'm looking for a way of selecting all smartphones from the database so does anyone know the raw SQL query to select all WooCommerce products by their tag?

Answer (score -1):

This will get you the results you want using a native WordPress query. Then you can traverse the results using the loop:

```
// Define Query Arguments
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'product_tag' => $tags
);

// Create the new query
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
// Get products number
$product_count = $loop->post_count;

// If results
if( $product_count > 0 ) :
  // Start the loop
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;

   /** Do stuff here **/

  endwhile;

else :
  _e('No product matching your criteria.');
endif; // endif $product_count > 0
```

Credit goes to [Remi Corson](http://www.remicorson.com/list-woocommerce-products-by-tags/) for this solution.

Comment: He insisted twice that he wanted an SQL query. This is not an SQL query.